# Append values of row with same values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have following data frame:

```
1 A a
1 A b
2 B c
1 A d
```

How do I append all the values of a row with same values to data frame:

```
1 A a,c,d
2 B c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `join` :

```
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  A  a
1  1  A  b
2  2  B  c
3  1  A  d

print (df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(', '.join).reset_index())
   a  b        c
0  1  A  a, b, d
1  2  B        c
```

Or if first column is `index`:

```
df.columns = ['a','b']
print (df)
   a  b
1  A  a
1  A  b
2  B  c
1  A  d

df1 = df.b.groupby([df.index, df.a]).apply(', '.join).reset_index(name='c')
df1.columns = ['a','b','c']
print (df1)
   a  b        c
0  1  A  a, b, d
1  2  B        c
```